# How to map texture between 2 similar meshes

Tags: 3d, blender, texture-mapping, meshlab

I have 2 models of an object that I captured using a 3D scanner in a .obj 3D mesh file. These 2 meshes represent the same object, but the actual meshes are different (due to small errors and noise during the capture process). Still, these 2 meshes align perfectly.

**I want to copy the texture in one of them into the other.** I'm looking for a way to "copy" the texture into Mesh A, from the closest node in Mesh B.

How could I achieve this using either Meshlab or Blender?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it can be done in Meshlab. But in Blender perhaps you can use the following:

If your objects are aligned correctly you should be able to paint the
MeshA object with the clone brush. This could work easier when you offset
the 2 meshes for a chosen view orientation.

Make sure that the 2 objects are joint during painting by selecting them
both in object mode and press Ctrl+J.

1. Change 'object mode' -> 'Texture Paint'
2. Use the 'F Clone' brush
3. Set the point to clone by using Ctrl+left_click

Answer (score 1):

In blender you can also [bake a texture](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Bake) from one model to another, while often thought of only being used to create normal maps, baking can also be used to create uv textures from procedural textures or transfer several textures to a single texture.

You can easily find tutorials on baking, the main points are to setup the uv's and have an image ready to receive the baked data, select the source then target and set the required options and bake.